# How to parse contained email in text file using regex?

Tags: java, regex

[image]

I have text file containing text from email as mentioned above .
I need to extract values for E2, E1, E0 and each of those for From:, Sent:  , To: , Subject:
Can we do it using regex expression ?

we can do like  "^(From|Sent|To|Subject):(.*)" regex in java .
But is there any comprehensive regex for above example of text ?

Comment: What's the problem with the regex you proposed?

Comment: It will not work in one shot .See there is pattern first we have header from sent to subject then region then it is repeating ..

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the raw message source.  You'll see there should be a uniform first header and there's always and always, only, a  blank line separating the headers from the actual message (the part you want).

You can create a regex to look for the first blank line after the first header, then extract the body.

Comment: There might be big paragraphs at place of E2, E1, E0

Comment: Thats fine, because you're only parsing after the first blank line.

Comment: Another approach is to just parse the headers and then whatever is left is your content.

Comment: There will be new line between header and content so logic should be based on blank line

Comment: thats what I said in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

Unsure if related, but some mail readers (thunderbird among others) store the mails in a text file with a determined format :

- separator line begins with `From` (ie From followed by a space and not a column) : this line is the begin of a mail
- separator is followed by header lines. Each header line has a format of :
      HEADERNAME: value
  where both HEADERNAME and value are arbitrary strings. The rule is that HEADERNAME must not be preceded by a space because a line beginning by a space is a continuation line
- the headers bloc is terminated by an empty line
- the remaining upto next `From` line is the body of the mail

If you are reading such a file, I strongly advice you to not rely on known HEARDERNAMES but to parse the file according to the above rules, or even better use the `mailbox` module that will do that for you and :

- has been thoroughly tested
- has many options to adapt to variations on mailbox format